# Directory ignored by "setup.py"

Tags: python, distutils

The Selenium setup.py can be found at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/setup.py.

When running "python setup.py sdist" the "firefox/test/py" directory 
is ignored for some reason though it's 
mentioned in the "package_dir" and in "packages".

Any ideas why it's ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory is ignored because it is not in the MANIFEST.

More info - http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html